# Callback not invoking when close button on "apprequests" FB.ui popup is pressed

Tags: javascript, facebook

[image: Close button]

If I dismiss the popup from FB.ui with method 'apprequests' using this close button, it doesn't appear to invoke my response callback, often leaving my program in a bad state. For example:

`FB.ui
  method: 'apprequests'
  message: "Hello"
  to: data.recipients # defined elsewhere
, (response) =>
  # this will never get invoked if the close button is pressed
  console.log("Completed facebook request.")`

Is this button supposed to invoke the callback, or is there another event that my app needs to hook into to respond to when the close button is pressed?